# converting Pandas series datetime "month" number to the month text

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, tuples, series

I can't convert a month number from a date in pandas to an integer or a number.

I give.  I have tried every which way I can think of to convert a pandas month number to the month name for ease of viewing. I get errors.  I have tried using month_name for pandas series, creating a dictionary of month numbers and month names (gives an error), I can convert the series to a string but not an int, I created a separate tuple, nothing seems to work.

I realize I need to convert the series (which  I can do math with) to a number.

using pandas series month name gives me this:

```
<bound method Pandas Delegate._add_ delegate accessors.<locals>._create_delegator_method.<locals>.f of <pandas.core.indexes.accessors.DatetimeProperties object at 0x000001F8A776D0F0>>
```

While not an error, also not useful.

Using my tuple I get the following error: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not Series.  And I get this because it works fine if instead of trying some manner to convert the Series to an integer, which gives "cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>."

```
'''
creating a tuple of month numbers
'''
num_to_month = ('tuple of months in order','January', 'February', 'March', 'Apil', 'May',
                'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')

'''
create list of new forecasts
'''
files_to_process = sorted(glob('*CAH_KEY_STRATEGY_DOC*.xlsx'))
print(files_to_process)

'''
update the files to process to add the fiscal quarter info and save back to same name
'''
for file in files_to_process:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df['fiscal_yr_qtr'] = pd.PeriodIndex([date - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1) + pd.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter(normalize=True, weekday=4,startingMonth=4, qtr_with_extra_week=1, variation='last') for date in df.task_date], freq='Q-APR')
    df['month'] = df.task_date.dt.month
    # y = df['month'].to_int
    # print(y)
    # z= int(y)
    # print(y)
    df['year'] = df.task_date.dt.year
    df['day'] = df.task_date.dt.day
    df['fiscal_qtr'] = pd.PeriodIndex([date - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1) + pd.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter(normalize=True, weekday=4,startingMonth=4, qtr_with_extra_week=1, variation='last') for date in df.task_date], freq='Q-APR').quarter
    df.loc[((df.task_date.dt.month >= 5) | ((df.task_date.dt.month == 4) & (df['fiscal_qtr'] == 1))), 'fiscal_yr'] = df.task_date.dt.year + 1
    df.loc[((df.task_date.dt.month <= 4) & (df['fiscal_qtr'] != 1)), 'fiscal_yr'] = df.task_date.dt.year
    df['total_expenses'] = df['costs'] + df['3rd_prty']
    df['total_spend'] = df['fees'] + df['costs'] + df['3rd_prty']
    # df['month_name'] = df.task_date.dt.month_name #added 8/18/2020
    # df['month_name'] = num_to_month[y] # this gives september
    df.to_excel(file, index=False)
    with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', datetime_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```

Comment: `df.task_date.dt.month_name()`

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in datetime format:
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"],format="%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
you can directly change the format as you want. Month as name is formatted with %B
check the documentation:
https://stackabuse.com/how-to-format-dates-in-python/
If you want another columns with this info just use
df["Date_2"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')